# Making associative array based on another associative array

Tags: bash, associative-array

I made an associative array as follows. To give a few details, the keys refer to specific files because I will be using this array in the context of a larger script (where the directory containing the files will be a getopts argument).

```
declare -A BAMREADS
echo "BAMREADS array is initialized"

BAMREADS[../data/file1.bam]=33285268
BAMREADS[../data/file2.bam]=28777698
BAMREADS[../data/file3.bam]=22388955

echo ${BAMREADS[@]}  # Output: 22388955 33285268 28777698
echo ${!BAMREADS[@]} # Output: ../data/file1.bam ../data/file2.bam ../data/file3.bam
```

So far, this array seems to behave as I expect. Now, I want to build another associative array based on this array. To be specific: my second array will have the same keys as my first one but I want to divide the values by a variable called $MIN.

I am not sure which of the following strategies is best and I can't seem to make either work.

**Strategy 1**: copy the array and modify the array?

```
MIN=33285268

declare -A BRAMFRACS
echo "BAMFRACS array is initialized"
BAMFRACS=("${BAMREADS[@]}")

echo ${BAMFRACS[@]}  # Output: 22388955 33285268 28777698
echo ${!BAMFRACS[@]} # Output: 0 1 2
```

This is not what I want for the keys. Even if it works, I would then need to perform the operation I mentioned on all the values.

**Stragegy 2**: build the second array when looping through the first.

```
MIN=33285268

declare -A BRAMFRACS
echo "BAMFRACS array is initialized"

for i in $(ls $BAMFILES/*bam)
do
    echo $i
    echo ${BAMREADS[$i]}
    BAMFRACS[$i] = ${BAMREADS[$i]} 
done

echo ${BAMFRACS[@]}
echo ${!BAMFRACS[@]}


#When I run this, I get the following error which I am unsure how to solve:

../data/file1.bam
33285268
script.bash: line 108: BAMFRACS[../data/file1.bam]: No such file or directory
../data/file2.bam
28777698
script.bash: line 108: BAMFRACS[../data/file2.bam]: No such file or directory
../data/file3.bam
22388955
script.bash: line 108: BAMFRACS[../data/file3.bam]: No such file or directory
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Build the new array from the old:

```
MIN=33285268

declare -A BRAMFRACS
for key in "${!BAMREADS[@]}"; do
    BRAMFRACS[$key]=$(( ${BAMREADS[$key]} / MIN ))
done
```

Comments on your code:

- Your first suggested code does not work as it copies the *values* from the associative array to the new array.  The values automatically gets the keys 0, 1 and 2 but the original keys are not copied.  You need to copy the array key by key as I have shown above. This way you assign the wanted value to the correct key.
- Your second suggested code contains a syntax error in that it has spaces around `=` in an assignment. This is where the errors that you see come from.  `variable = value` is interpreted as "the command `variable` executed with the operands `=` and `value`".
- If you wish to iterate over a set of pathnames, *don't use `ls`*.  Instead just do `for pathname in "$BAMFILES"/*bam; do`.
- Quote you variable expansions.
- Consider using `printf` instead of `echo` to output variable data.

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 9):

To answer the more general question about copying associative arrays.

The `bash` maintainers made the unfortunate decision to copy the ksh93 API rather than the zsh one when they introduced their own associative arrays in 4.0.

`ksh93`/`bash` do support setting an associative array as a whole, but it's with the:

```
hash=([k1]=v1 [k2]=v2)
```

syntax. While with `zsh`, it's

```
hash=(k1 v1 k2 v2)
```

(support for the `([k]=v...)` ksh93 syntax was also added later on for compatibility).

What that means though is that with ksh93 and bash, it's very tricky to create  a hash that way from an arbitrary list of keys and values.

With the `zsh` syntax, you just need to pass the list as alternating keys  and values. For instance, to copy two associative arrays:

```
h2=("${(@kv)h1}")
```

Or from a CSV with two columns:

```
IFS=$'\n,'; h=($(<file.csv))
```

Or from arrays of key and values:

```
h=("${(@)keys:^values}")
```

With the `ksh93`/`bash` syntax, while there's `"${!h[@]}"` and `"${h[@]}"` to expand to the list of keys and values (like `"${(@k)h}"` and `"${(@v)h}"` in `zsh`), there's no operator to expand to both keys and values in the `[key]=value` syntax expected by `h=(...)` (the `"${(@kv)h}"` in `zsh`).

A trick you can use in those shells to copy associative arrays though (other than copying elements in a loop), is to use the output of `typeset -p`.

For instance, the equivalent of `zsh`'s `h2=("${(@kv)h1}")` to copy `h1` into `h2` could be done in `ksh93` or `bash` with:

```
h1_definition=$(typeset -p h1) &&
  eval "typeset -A h2=${h1_definition#*=}"
```

Which with `bash` you can shorten to:

```
h1_definition=$(typeset -p h1) &&
  typeset -A h2="${h1_definition#*=}"
```

(While like in ksh93, `typeset -A h=value` is short for `typeset -A h=([0]=value)` in `bash`, if `value` starts  with `(` and ends with `)`, then the content is interpreted as a compound associative assignment as if passed to `eval` (even if the `(` are quoted or the result of some expansion)).

In the end, it's about as easy to use the loop instead:

```
for k in "${!h1[@]}"; do h2[$k]=${h1[$k]}; done
```

Comment: *which with `bash` (≥4.4) you can shorten to `typeset -A h2="${h1_definition#*=}"`. I was confused why this wasn't working for me on CentOS 7 (Bash 4.2.x) so I tried 3.x through 5.x by [pulling images from Docker](https://gist.github.com/ernstki/b782cc7f2a29ec01c1f4355f2dd312cc), and with earlier Bashes you'll either get an error or just a literal string assigned to `[0]` instead (but no error).

Comment: Any particular reason why using `typeset` instead of `declare`? Judging from `help typeset` it seems `declare` is the "real" command.

Comment: @MestreLion, `typeset` is the name ksh chose nearly 40 years ago and is supported by all Bourne-like shells that have variable types including bash, so that's the one I'm used to. bash decided to call it `declare` for some reason, but has always supported `typeset` as an alias and will likely support it forever, like other shells. There have been more shells recently adding `declare` as an alias for `typeset` for compatibility with `bash`, but it will take more than that to change my habits :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following bash assigns the values from associative array AA2 (which may be unset) into another associative array AA1 (much must be declared -A).

```bash
LIST="$(declare -p AA2 2>/dev/null)"
[[ "$LIST" ]] && AA1+=${LIST#*=}
```

- `declare -p` echoes the value of a variable as a `declare` statement which can be directly passed into the interpreter without any word splitting problems.
- `${LIST#*=}` removes the equals sign and everything before it.
- The hiding of an error (`2>/dev/null`) during `declare` and the non-zero length test (`[[ "$LIST" ]]`) allow AA2 to be unset.
- Unexpected results (not errors) will happen if AA1 or AA2 are not associative arrays.

Answer (score -3):

this should do it (can also add additional key-value):

```
declare -A origDict=( [keya]=value_a [keyb]=value_b [keyc]=value_c )
declare -a newDict=( echo ${origDict[*]} [keynew]=new_value )
```

Comment: Mostly works, but you lose the original keys, as `newDict` is declared as just an ordinary (numeric-indexed) array in this case. If you run `declare -p newDict` afterward, you will see:
`declare -a newDict='([0]="new_value" [1]="value_c" [2]="value_b" [3]="value_a")'`. Thanks for your answer, though!

Comment: if `newDict` is an ordinary array instead of an associative one, then this fails to answer the original question